Cannot get thick client on python oracledb working. Finds libclntsh.so - but fails at libnnz11.so
This is my python script.
import oracledb
import os
import sys

os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = "/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client"
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client"
print ('#######\nos environ :' , os.environ,'\n#######')
oracledb.init_oracle_client()

When I run it I get:
#######
os environ : environ({'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 'HISTCONTROL': 'ignoredups', 'SYSTEMD_COLORS': 'false', 'HISTSIZE': '1000', 'HOSTNAME': 'ip-172-31-15-229.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal', 'PWD': '/home/ec2-user', 'LOGNAME': 'ec2-user', 'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'tty', 'MOTD_SHOWN': 'pam', 'HOME': '/home/ec2-user', 'DPI_DEBUG_LEVEL': '64', 'LANG': 'C.UTF-8', 'LS_COLORS': 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.m4a=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.opus=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:', 'SSH_CONNECTION': '49.199.255.93 2316 172.31.15.229 22', 'XDG_SESSION_CLASS': 'user', 'SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED': '', 'TERM': 'xterm', 'LESSOPEN': '||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s', 'USER': 'ec2-user', 'SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE': '', 'SHLVL': '1', 'XDG_SESSION_ID': '8', 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 'S_COLORS': 'auto', 'SSH_CLIENT': '49.199.255.93 2316 22', 'which_declare': 'declare -f', 'PATH': 'LOCAL_PATH:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin', 'SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED': '', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus', 'MAIL': '/var/spool/mail/ec2-user', 'SSH_TTY': '/dev/pts/2', 'OLDPWD': '/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib', 'BASH_FUNC_which%%': '() {  ( alias;\n eval ${which_declare} ) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot "$@"\n}', '_': '/usr/bin/python3', 'ORACLE_HOME': '/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client', 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH': '/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client'})
#######
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: ODPI-C 5.3.0
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: debugging messages initialized at level 64
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: Context Parameters:
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: Environment Variables:
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782:     ORACLE_HOME => "/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client"
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782:     LD_LIBRARY_PATH => "/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client"
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: check module directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: module name is /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oracledb/thick_impl.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load in dir /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oracledb
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load with name /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oracledb/libclntsh.so
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load by OS failure: /home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/oracledb/libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load with OS search heuristics
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load with name libclntsh.so
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load with name libclntsh.so.19.1
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.782: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.19.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load with name libclntsh.so.18.1
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.18.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load with name libclntsh.so.12.1
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load with name libclntsh.so.11.1
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.11.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load with name libclntsh.so.20.1
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.20.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load with name libclntsh.so.21.1
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load by OS failure: libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: check ORACLE_HOME
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load in dir /home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load with name /home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib/libclntsh.so
ODPI [11611] 2024-07-31 04:28:04.783: load by OS failure: libnnz11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    oracledb.init_oracle_client()
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 505, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 530, in oracledb.thick_impl.init_oracle_client
  File "src/oracledb/impl/thick/utils.pyx", line 457, in oracledb.thick_impl._raise_from_info
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libnnz11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html for help

My folder /home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib is set up thus:
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-229 ~]$ ls -l /home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib
total 77232
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user      449 Jul 30 15:11 BASIC_LITE_README
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    25420 Jul 30 15:11 adrci
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    47860 Jul 30 15:11 genezi
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 ec2-user ec2-user       56 Jul 31 03:09 libclntsh.so -> /home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 53865194 Jul 30 15:11 libclntsh.so.11.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  7996693 Jul 30 15:11 libnnz11.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  1973074 Jul 30 15:11 libocci.so.11.1
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  9897206 Jul 30 15:11 libociicus.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user   164942 Jul 30 15:11 libocijdbc11.so
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  2091135 Jul 30 15:11 ojdbc5.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user  2739616 Jul 30 15:11 ojdbc6.jar
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user   192365 Jul 30 15:11 uidrvci
-rw-r--r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user    66779 Jul 30 15:11 xstreams.jar

Running on AWS Linux EC2 instance :
NAME="Amazon Linux"
VERSION="2023"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="2023"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:al2023"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux 2023.5.20240722"

PS. My final destination is getting this working with AWS serverless. So I will build that link in the python script. Something like
subprocess.run(["ln -s /tmp/python39_loaded/libclntsh.so.11.1 /tmp/python39_loaded/libclntsh.so"], shell=True)

But I first trying to get this working on an EC2 I created for the purpose of testing this.
What am I doing wrong that after finding libclntsh.so, oracledb cannot find libnnz11.so?

On Linux you must set the library search path externally before the process starts.  Also, with Instant Client, never set ORACLE_HOME because this can lead to clashes (and isn't necessary for normal use).  Finally, why use such an old version of Instant Client?

Thank you Chris. Setting export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ec2-user/linux_oracle_client/lib appears to have got me further along. Not getting errors anymore when invoking oracledb.init_oracle_client(). Next step is go get this working on AWS Serverless. Wish me luck... As to why client 11. Well I am trying to connect to an production Oracle 11G so I just started with the client 11. As to why my government organisation is still on 11G in production, don't ask. THanks heaps for you answer.
